# Rails 5 Stripe::AuthenticationError - create product

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm building an app with Rails 5, Ruby 2.4.0 and the `stripe` gem.

I have a product scaffold, and when I create a product, if it saves i want it to then send the product to stripe and create the product there, and return the stripe product id to the product record.

The product its self is saving as I can query it in console and it appears on the index page, however when it sends to stripe I get the following error.

[image: Stripe Authentication Error]

My ApplicationController file:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  require "stripe"

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

My FULL stripe initializer file: `config/initializers/stripe.rb`

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
  :publishable_key => ENV['STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY'],
  :secret_key => ENV['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY']
}

Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
```

My Product controller create action:

```
  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }

        product = Stripe::Product.create({
          name: @product.prod_name,
          type: @product.prod_type,
          statement_descriptor: @product.statement_descriptor,
          unit_label: @product.unit_label,
          product_status: @product.product_status
        })

      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Any assistance here would be greatly appreciated as I have very little experience with stripe and I cant seem to sort this out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure `STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY` & `STRIPE_SECRET_KEY` to your `config/application.yml` file

Look you need to set stripe [`STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY` & `STRIPE_SECRET_KEY`](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/rails#testing-the-integration) for setting these keys securely you can use [`figaro gem`](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) after installing Figaro gem then a file will create inside `config` directory which name `application.yml` you can set your keys like this

```
STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY: pk_test_xxxxxxxxxx
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY: pk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Then update your `stripe.rb` inside `config/initializers/`

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
    :publishable_key => ENV['STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY'],
    :secret_key => ENV['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY']
}
Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
```

That's it, you have done this.

Comment: So once this is created how could i go about adding the generated product_id that stripe makes and save it to the product i created in rails?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the publishable key and secret key as environmental variables (or hard-code them)